# i cant use ngif on arrow in angular 6

Tags: angular, arrows, angular-ng-if

this is my html file :

```
<div class="site"><a routerLink="site" (click)="myMove()"  class="text">
  <mat-icon svgIcon="site" class="icon"><span  class="fa fa-caret-right caret1"  *ngIf="text2"></span>
    <div *ngIf="text" class="text1">Site</div>
  </mat-icon>
</a></div>
```

this is my css file :

```
.text {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 40px;
}
.caret1 {
  margin-left: 30px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

and this is my typescript file :

```
export class GeneralManagementComponent implements OnInit {

  text = true;
  text2 = false;
   constructor() {
   }

   ngOnInit() {
   }

  public myMove() {
  this.text2 = true;
  this.text = false;
  }
 }
```

And what I want to do When I click on the link, show the **arrow**, and when I use **ngif** it does not work for **arrow**. But when I use **ngif** for another div,its work.
I do not know why I can not use **ngif** for **arrow**.

i make my problem here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-slmxmk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

i useing angular 6.

Comment: .caret1 appears to have no dimensions, using the console are you sure it's not appearing?

Comment: I doubt it has anything to do with `*ngIf` but rather svg and your inner html structure. Remove the `*ngIf` and see if that even works and let us know. I would also recommend you create an [mcve] using https://www.stackblitz.com

Comment: it work when i remove <mat-icon></mat-icon> but i need this what should i do?

Comment: I do not think `mat-icon` supports inner html. It is an icon, not text plus content.

Comment: See also https://material.angular.io/components/icon/examples

Comment: if i use text2 = true  it work but not working when i use link

Comment: Again, hard to help you without a [mcve], create one using https://www.stackblitz.com/ and I/we might be able to help you.

Comment: Okay, take just a few minutes

Comment: i make my problem here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-slmxmk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html please help me

Comment: A little late but nice work on providing the [mcve]! By providing one you make it much easier for others to help you find an answer. I gave you an upvote, you now have enough rep to upvote others including the answer below.

Comment: Thank you for upvote. After this, I will try to make my questions better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**component.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {MatIconRegistry} from '@angular/material/icon';
import {DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  text = true;
  constructor(
  private matIconRegistry: MatIconRegistry,
  private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer
  ){
        this.matIconRegistry.addSvgIcon(
      'site',
      this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('../assets/icons/web.svg')
    );  
  }
    public myMove() {
    this.text = !this.text;
  }
}
```

**html**

```
<a (click)="myMove()" class="text">
  <mat-icon *ngIf="!text" svgIcon="site" class="icon">
    <span  class="divstyle1" >&#x27A4;</span>
    </mat-icon>
    <mat-icon *ngIf="text" svgIcon="site" class="icon">
    <div  class="text1">Site</div>
  </mat-icon>
</a>
```

link:
[blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n12fga?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)